# How to align controls vertically?

Tags: sapui5

I have several elements on screen in XML file

```xml
<layout:VerticalLayout xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" xmlns="sap.m">
  <Input />
  <Button />
  <!-- ... -->
</layout:VerticalLayout>
```

How can I add something like layout gravity or align the controls vertically? E.g. I want the elements in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using the `sap.m` library anyway, I would recommend to use the `sap.m.VBox` control (or `sap.m.HBox` for horizontal layouts)
The `VBox` does exactly the same as the `VerticalLayout` and more (you can specify alignment, justification in a truly flexible way).

The `VBox` and `HBox` inherit from `sap.m.FlexBox`, see these examples on what you can do: https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.FlexBox